# ¿Como hacer que a la hora de insertar en la tabla nuevos elementos esta se extienda hacia abajo del mismo tamaño?

Tags: html, css

Estoy imprimiendo resultados en la tabla de 5 en 5, a la hora de darle a ver mas este agrega 5 mas, pero no los agrega del mismo tamaño como estaba inicialmente, como pudiera hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así esta antes de darle a ver mas, ahora cuando le doy a ver mas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo hacer para que cuando muestre los 5 mas los muestre del mismo tamaño como estaba originalmente?

Aquí les dejo mi código:

```css
#finished_products {
  text-align: center;
}

#finished_products_table {
  margin-top: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 8px groove #72d3c6;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#table_container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 384px;
}

#table_container table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 149, 144, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
}

#table_container table input {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #8cdbd7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#table_container table button {
  max-width: 5%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #8cdbd7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #69E9E2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#table_container table th,
#table_container table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#table_container table td {
  text-align: center;
}

#table_container table:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: rgba(0, 149, 144);
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="finished_products">
  <div id="finished_products_table">
    <div id="table_container">
      <table>
        <colgroup>
          <col width="10%" />
          <col width="10%" />
          <col width="10%" />
          <col width="10%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <input v-model="product" @input="findproduct" placeholder="Search..." />
            <a href="index.php"><button>Back</button></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Name:</th>
          <th>Lot:</th>
          <th>Quantity packed</th>
          <th>Quantity of pallets</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table id="products_table">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="10%" />
          <col width="10%" />
          <col width="10%" />
          <col width="10%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr v-for="i in listFinishedproducts">
          <td>{{i.id}}</td>
          <td>{{i.lot}}</td>
          <td>{{i.quantity_packed}}</td>
          <td>{{i.pallet}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4"><a href="#" @click="hola">hola</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Creo que ocupas hacer uso de Javascript, ocupas darle funcionalidad a tu página.

Comment: Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un [mre]

Comment: Creo que el problema es que cuando llegan mas registros el html trata de ajustar el contenido al tamaño del contendor, lo que debes hacer es cuando lleguen los resultados, por js modificas el css y le aumentas el tamaño

Answer (score 0):

tienes fijada la altura de tu table_container, intenta con height: auto, de esta manera se ajustara automaticamente a tu contenido

```css
#finished_products {
  text-align: center;
}

#finished_products_table {
  margin-top: 150px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 8px groove #72d3c6;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#table_container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: auto;
}

#table_container table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 149, 144, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
}

#table_container table input {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #8cdbd7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#table_container table button {
  max-width: 5%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #8cdbd7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #69E9E2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#table_container table th,
#table_container table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#table_container table td {
  text-align: center;
}

#table_container table:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: rgba(0, 149, 144);
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="finished_products">
  <div id="finished_products_table">
    <div id="table_container">
      <table>
        <colgroup>
          <col width="10%" />
          <col width="10%" />
          <col width="10%" />
          <col width="10%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <input v-model="product" @input="findproduct" placeholder="Search..." />
            <a href="index.php"><button>Back</button></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Name:</th>
          <th>Lot:</th>
          <th>Quantity packed</th>
          <th>Quantity of pallets</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table id="products_table">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="10%" />
          <col width="10%" />
          <col width="10%" />
          <col width="10%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr v-for="i in listFinishedproducts">
          <td>{{i.id}}</td>
          <td>{{i.lot}}</td>
          <td>{{i.quantity_packed}}</td>
          <td>{{i.pallet}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4"><a href="#" @click="hola">hola</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```