# ¿Por qué a la hora de agregar elementos a mi tabla el ancho incrementa?

Tags: html, css

La tabla está bien hace rato, pero decidí meterle un nuevo elemento, que es el id, la cosa es que al darle ver más e insertar nuevos elementos el witdh se incrementa, por qué pasa esto? y como solucionarlo si llego a meter mas campos y que no pase esto?

Antes de darle a ver más:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de darle a ver más:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si se puede apreciar muy bien que está un poco más ancha la segunda imagen, es decir la tabla se alarga horizontalmente un poco más.

aqui les dejo el estilo y la estructura de esta:

vista:

```
<div id="finished_products">
        <div id="finished_products_table">
            <div id="table_container">
                <table>
                    <colgroup>
                        <col width="10%"/>
                        <col width="10%" />
                        <col width="10%" />
                        <col width="10%" />
                        <col width="10%" />
                    </colgroup>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <input v-model="product" @input="findproduct" placeholder="Search..." />
                            <a href="index.php"><button>Back</button></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Lot</th>
                        <th>Quantity packed</th>
                        <th>Quantity of pallets</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table id="products_table">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col width="10%"/>
                        <col width="10%"/>
                        <col width="10%"/>
                        <col width="10%"/>
                        <col width="10%" />
                    </colgroup>
                    <tr v-for="i in listFinishedproducts">
                        <td>{{i.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.lot}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.quantity_packed}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.pallet}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5"><a href="#" @click = "hola">{{message}}</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#table_container {
    display:inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 384px;
}

#table_container table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 149, 144, 0.8);
    width: 100%;
}

#table_container table input{
    width: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #8cdbd7;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}


#table_container table button{
    max-width: 15%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #8cdbd7;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #69E9E2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#table_container table th, #table_container table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    word-break: break-word;
  
}

#table_container table td {
    text-align: center;
}

#table_container table:first-child {
    position: sticky;
    background-color:rgba(0, 149, 144);
    top: 0;
    
}


#table_container #products_table th, #table_container #products_table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    word-break: break-word;
    font-size: 18px;
    
}

#table_container a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}


#table_container a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: white;
}
```

gracias :)

Comment: Saludos. Prueba agregando en los estilos (CSS) una altura mínima para los tr.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como hacer que a la hora de insertar en la tabla nuevos elementos esta se extienda hacia abajo del mismo tamaño?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/365824/como-hacer-que-a-la-hora-de-insertar-en-la-tabla-nuevos-elementos-esta-se-extie)

Answer (score 0):

Sin entrar en detalles, te sugiero utilizar las Developer Tools que tengas según el navegador web en cuestión; en muchos casos pulsas F12 y te aparece lo respectivo.  Así puedes seleccionar un elemento de tus tablas, y rastrear cuál estilo es el que efectivamente está utilizando.  Suele pasar que pensamos estar usando uno en particular, y resulta que es otro en realidad.  Saludos